# Remote Desktop Access : know which user is already connected

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-connection

I use Remote Desktop Access to access a distant computer. Sometimes I am told another user is already connected (which is no issue in an of itself) but I want to know who it is to get in touch with them. How do I do that ?

I tried to run `qwinsta`, `query session`, `quser` but all I get is "No session is available for " or "No user is available for ".

The specific syntax `qwinsta /SERVER:<machine-name>` yields error 1722 "The RPC-Server is not available."

I do use a gateway to RDP, but no VPN it seems.

Comment: Do you use a vpn to establish the connection to the remote site?

Comment: I don't think so, but just in case, how would I know ?

Comment: And even if I did use a VPN, if something like `ping <machine-name>` works then I know everything is working as far as communicating with the machine, no ?

Comment: "...ping <machine-name> works then I know everything is working as far as communicating with the machine", yes

Comment: So then how do I know if I am using a VPN, and how might I be impacted ?

Comment: On my side, when I connect to a VPN, qwinsta returns the same error. To check if VPN is connected, go to Settings -> Network & Internet -> VPN.

Comment: Oh you mean using a VPN in general, not just when RDP'ing. Then the answer is probably no when working from my offices (and definitely yes when working from elsewhere). However even when in the offices the settings page you mention has at the top a red message : " *Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization " then everything is grayed out and unclickable. But there is no mention of a particular VPN connection - but as the message suggests, it could be hidden.

Comment: Also of note, I use a gateway when RDP'ing.

Comment: Yes, VPN in general. If you are currently at the office and can RDP to another machine, RDP to it, then on your PC, test `qwinsta /SERVER:<machine-name>`. Do you still get an error?